# Conditional Formatting Based On Another Column Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want to use color scale while doing conditional formatting in a column, based on the color scale used on another column. For example, if in A Column I am having names of students and in B column I am having their scores. I have done condition formatting using color scale in B column like lowest will be red and highest will be white and other shades of red for the scores in between. I want the column with names to have the same formatting as the scores. Kindly help

Comment: not possible without script

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by replicating the formulas for your conditional formatting in Column B to also be reflective in column A.

If for example you have the value of 25 in column B and what to give this a red text colour. You would create a conditional formating rule that has the following settings

**Apply to Range** - B:B

**Format Rules** - Text Contains - 25

**Formatting style** - red text

[image: Column B Cond Format]

You can then apply this format to column A with the following settings for a conditional formatting rule in column A

**Apply to Range** - A2:A10 (extend to the range you need)

**Format Rules** - Custom Formula is - =$B2=25

**Formatting style** - red text

[image: Column A Conditional Format]

If you then enter 25 into column B it should also format column A. You would then need to replicate this for every conditional format rule that you have

Comment: The question is for Colour Scale not Single Colour as you have shown!